# ConcurrentModificationException on android's Apache BasicCookieStore

Tags: java, android, apache, concurrency, crash

We've been getting crashes in the wild in our android app on ConcurrentModificationException.

Basically, in one of our library, it calls org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore's addCookie method and it throws the ConcurrentModificationException.  Here is the relevant stack trace:

```
ArrayList.java line 569: java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next
Collections.java line 960: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next
....
```

It looks like ConcurrentModificationException is getting thrown because there are 2 (or more) thread trying to access the array list internal to the BasicCookieStore class.  Now, given that BasicCookieStore class is marked as ThreadSafe and all the array list access method seems to be synchronized.  What can cause this?  Hints?

Here's the source code for BasicCookieStore for reference: [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/apache-http/+/master/src/org/apache/http/impl/client/BasicCookieStore.java)

Comment: Could you please provide the full stack trace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessarily caused by a weak thread-safety. It can also happen when you call Iterator.next() for the structure which is modified before that iterator reaches his terminal state. Even in a single thread.
For example this code will throw ConcurrentModificationException:

```
    ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    arrayList.add(new Object());
    arrayList.add(new Object());
    arrayList.add(new Object());
    //...
    for (Object o : arrayList) { //iterating with iterator
        arrayList.remove(0); // perform some modification while 
                             //iterating over the structure

    }
```

If you investigate the ArrayList source code you will see that every modification increments the `int modCount` field. When you create an iterator via ArrayList.iterator() it takes a snapshot of modCount and compares it to current list's `modCount` on every iteration to fail if they are not equal.

**Update** : I made an investigation and found some problem code of `BasicCookieStore`. I managed to find only one possibility for `ConcurrentModificationException` to happen : you call `BasicCookieStore.toString()` in one thread while some modifications (for example `addCookie()`) happening in another.

This class is almost safe for fail-fast iterators : all methods are `synchronized` except the `toString()`. 
Let's see it code :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return cookies.toString();
}
```

It invokes the `ArrayList.toString()`:

```
public String toString() {
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    if (! it.hasNext())
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[');
    for (;;) {
        E e = it.next();
        sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
        if (! it.hasNext())
            return sb.append(']').toString();
        sb.append(',').append(' ');
    }
}
```

You can see that it uses an iterator. So consider that while `toString()` is executed we do some modification (and it is really possible because of lack of synchronization), for example `addCookie` :

```
public synchronized void addCookie(Cookie cookie) {
    if (cookie != null) {
        // first remove any old cookie that is equivalent
        for (Iterator<Cookie> it = cookies.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            if (cookieComparator.compare(cookie, it.next()) == 0) {
                it.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!cookie.isExpired(new Date())) {
            cookies.add(cookie);
        }
    }
}
```

This method performs modifications to the list, generally, not very often, but it does.
You can see for your own that there is a possibility to increment `modCount` while `toString`'s iterator isn't at his terminal state. So when it happens - `toString`'s `iterator.next()` will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: maybe that why the latest version of BasicCookieStore has a different impl: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/client/BasicCookieStore.java  To bad I don't think this is used on android yet.

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc of ConcurrentModificationException :

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has
>   been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread
>   issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of
>   an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a
>   thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the
>   collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this
>   exception.

here is the link : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html